# ImageView memory leak - simple images

Tags: android, image, memory-leaks, bitmap, mat

I created a class whose task is to match the appropriate images to the respective ImageVew's.

Unfortunately, this leads to a memory leak ...

As someone on stackoverflow suggested in similar problem, I converted the images from the Resources to Bitmaps.

My class looks like this:

```
public ImageAdjuster(Context context, ImageView iv1,
        ImageView iv2, ImageView iv3, ImageView iv4, ImageView iv5,
        ImageView iv6, ImageView iv7) {

    this.iv1 = iv1;
    this.iv2 = iv2;
    this.iv3 = iv3;
    this.iv4 = iv4;
    this.iv5 = iv5;
    this.iv6 = iv6;
    this.iv7 = iv7;
    this.context = context;

    loadAllDrawables();
}

private void loadAllDrawables() {
    imageResourceMap = new HashMap<String, Integer>();

    imageResourceMap.put("image1", R.drawable.image1);
    imageResourceMap.put("image2", R.drawable.image2);
    imageResourceMap.put("image3", R.drawable.image3);
    imageResourceMap.put("image4", R.drawable.image4);
    imageResourceMap.put("image5",
            R.drawable.image5);
    imageResourceMap.put("image6",
            R.drawable.image6);
    imageResourceMap.put("image7",
            R.drawable.image7);


    loadBitmaps();
}

private void loadBitmaps() {
    imageBitmap = new HashMap<String, Bitmap>();
    for (String s : imageResourceMap.keySet()) {
        Bitmap tmp = getBitmapFromRes(imageResourceMap.get(s));

        imageBitmap.put(s, tmp);
    }

    imageResourceMap = null;
}

private Bitmap getBitmapFromRes(int resId) {
    Bitmap tmp = null;
    Bitmap b = null;
    try {
        BitmapFactory.Options o = new BitmapFactory.Options();
        o.inJustDecodeBounds = true;

        InputStream fis = context.getResources().openRawResource(resId);
        tmp = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(fis, null, o);
        fis.close();

        BitmapFactory.Options o2 = new BitmapFactory.Options();
        fis = context.getResources().openRawResource(resId);
        b = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(fis, null, o2);
        fis.close();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } finally {
        if (tmp != null) {
            tmp.recycle();
            tmp = null;
        }
    }
    return b;
}

public void setCorrectImages(Miner miner) {

    iv1.setImageBitmap(imageBitmap.get("image1"));
    iv2.setImageBitmap(imageBitmap.get("image2"));
    iv3.setImageBitmap(imageBitmap.get("image3"));
    iv4.setImageBitmap(imageBitmap.get("image4"));
    iv5.setImageBitmap(imageBitmap.get("image5"));
    iv6.setImageBitmap(imageBitmap.get("image6"));
    iv7.setImageBitmap(imageBitmap.get("image7"));

    iv1.setAdjustViewBounds(true);
    iv2.setAdjustViewBounds(true);
    iv3.setAdjustViewBounds(true);
    iv4.setAdjustViewBounds(true);
    iv5.setAdjustViewBounds(true);
    iv6.setAdjustViewBounds(true);
    iv7.setAdjustViewBounds(true);

}

public void recycleImageBitmaps() {
    for (Bitmap b : imageBitmap.values()) {
        if (b != null) {
            b.recycle();
        }
    }

}
```

In my activity i recycle images **onDestroy** and init it **onCreate**

I am using MAT to locate the leak. Look at printscreens:

**Diagram**
[image: Diagram]
**Suspects**
[image: Suspects]
**Details**
[image: Details]
[image: Details]

Each opening of this branch leads to the same view ;/

I have read many guides how to fix my problem, but none of them helped me

Thank you all for any aid, and of course I'm sorry for my english...

Comment: try reducing size of images like this http://pastie.org/9148591

Comment: I have a very similar issue. Did you find the cause?

Answer (score 1):

Why would you transform resources to bitmaps ? android has a very effective way of loading resources, just setting the image resource to the image view should be very effective in my opinion.